# Apache Pig word count program

Tags: apache-pig

In word count program how to find the most occurred word and least occurred word in pig. how to use MAX function here.

the output I am seeing like this

(Naveen,3)
(is,5)

here the out put I need is "is"

Answer (score 0):

you can use orderBy and limit :-

A = Load 'file' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray, count:int);

B = order A by count ; -- by default it will be ascending oder

C = limit B 1 ;

D = Foreach C generate name ;

dump D ;

B = order A by count desc ;

C = limit B 1 ;

D = Foreach C generate name ;

dump D ;

Answer (score 0):

Below example will help you to get to top 5 count

```
infiles = load '/hdfs/bhavesh/Youtube_POC/Youtube/0222/{0,1,2,3,4}.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as 
 (videoid:chararray,uploader:chararray,age:int,category:chararray,length:int,views:int,rate:int,rating:int,comments:int,related_id:chararray);
files = FILTER infiles BY category is not null;
grpn_for_catagories = group files by category;
cnt_for_catagories = foreach grpn_for_catagories generate group, COUNT(files.videoid) as counting;
sorted_for_catagories_desc = order cnt_for_catagories by counting desc;
top5_for_catagories = limit sorted_for_catagories_desc 5;
```

Detail Explanation is available in

http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/08/proof-of-concept-or-poc-on-youtube-data.html

Hope it Helps!!!...

Answer (score 0):

A = load 'file' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray, count:int);

B = order A by count;

C = limit B 1 ;

D = foreach C generate name ;

dump D ;